# Serializable in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android app, I had a `TreeMap` that I could happily put in a `Bundle` like

```
bundle.putSerializable("myHappyKey", myHappyTreeMap);
```

but now that I'm porting my app to Kotlin, Android Studio complains that `Serializable!` is required, but it's finding a `Map` instead.

How do I deal with this?

**EDIT** The warning seems to vanish if I cast my map to a `Serializable`. Is this the way?

**EDIT 2** I am declaring and initialising `myHappyTreeMap` as

```
var myHappyTreeMap: Map<Int, Double> = mapOf()
```

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html) says that maps initialised using `mapOf()` are serializable. If the docs says so…

Comment: What is the types in your map? The two type are `Serializable`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TreeMap` and various other `Map` implementations implement `Serializable` but the `Map` interface itself does not implement `Serializable`.

I see some options:

1. Make sure the type of `myHappyTreeMap` is not simply `Map` but `TreeMap` or some other `Map` subtype that implements `Serializable`. e.g.:

   ```
   val myHappyTreeMap: TreeMap = ...
   ```
2. Cast your `Map` instance as `Serializable` (only recommended if you *know* the `Map` instance type implements `Serializable` otherwise you will get a `ClassCastException`). e.g.:

   ```
   bundle.putSerializable("myHappyKey", myHappyTreeMap as Serializable)
   ```
3. Check your `Map` instance and if it isn't `Serializable` then make a copy of it using a `Map` implementation that is. e.g.:

   ```
   bundle.putSerializable("myHappyKey", when (myHappyTreeMap) {
       is Serializable -> myHappyTreeMap
       else -> LinkedHashMap(myHappyTreeMap)
   })
   ```

Comment: Suppose I prefer to cast to `Serializable`, how would I know for sure that a `Map` that I declare like `Map<Int, Double>`, for example, and initialise with `mapOf()` is going to implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Ah, the documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html) says that these maps are serializable. In practice, I found that it generates a LinkedHashMap. This may not be true in the future, but if the doc says that `mapOf()` produces a `Serializable`, then it may be safe to assume that it'll Just Work™.

Comment: @Morpheu5 I've updated the second option in my answer based on your comments and have also added a third option (check for `is Serializable` first and then make a copy of the map if necessary).

Comment: I should add that, at least in this case, I really didn't care if the map was a TreeMap, that was the toe I was using when I originally coded this in Java. Thanks for your answer.